# Where do I find Curie in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I bought the Overseer's Guardian in Fallout 4 then gave it to Curie. After that I sent her to sanctuary, but now she's gone.

How can I find Curie? I know there are console commands but I cannot use them because I'm playing on the PS4.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ The accepted answer to that question covers this case, too. Second numbered list, #2, third bullet.

Answer (score 10):

Curie has a verified bug on the PS4 whereupon dismissal, she will return to the medical room in Vault 81. This is regardles of where you send her in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble finding your Companions/NPCs in your settlements you can always build the bell item, located in the miscellaneous section of your resource tab. Once rung, all NPCs should make their way toward it, eventually. It does take a little while as they walk somewhat slowly.

Comment: I have built the bell and used it but curie didn't come

Comment: Have you checked your other settlements. Maybe you accidentally sent her somewhere else. If not then I can only imagine it is a bug. I do not know how to fix that unfortunately :(